# Adobe illustrator, how to make 3D object with multiple depths and positions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I would like to create something analogous to a 3D pathway, with walls and a floor. Something like this:

[image]

This was made using a hack. I first extruded the walls (50 pt depth), then the "floor" (0 pt) which had to be translated down to meet the bottom of the walls, because the walls were extruded up and down simultaneously, putting the floor in the middle.

Ideally, I would be able to rotate everything together, and specify the offset (in the direction of the extrusion), depth, *and* direction of extrusion (extruding up, down, or both) of different sets of objects independently.

But I would settle for just being able to set the direction of the extrusion. Is that possible? Does someone have another suggestion for how to accomplish this?

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution which could be applied to an arbitrary pathway shape (i.e. a curved hallway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with 3/4 of a rectangle... `Effect > 3d > Extrude and Bevel` and then adjust...

[image]

In this instance, the piece is rotated and the extrude depth controls how "long" the piece is. In order to alter the depth of the "sides", merely select the 2 end anchor points of the rectangle and move them to create longer "side" segments.

Note that achieving the multi-coloring is *not* possible as one object in Illustrator. You'll need to **Expand Appearance** and alter values for that.

I often find setting the **Shading** to "no shading" and the expanding the appearance is easier as it allows me to then apply individual gradients to the parts. Of course, you then lose the ability to further rotate or extrude if necessary.

Illustrator's 3D is exceptionally rudimentary and not designed to create 3D "scenes".

To apply a pattern to a specific side, you first create **Symbol** of the pattern. Draw a large rectangle, fill it with your pattern, then drag that to the **Symbols Panel**.

You can then use the **Map Art** button in the 3D effect to apply the pattern to a specific surface:

[image]

Works on curved surfaces as well...

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to add a pattern to the floor which means I can't use this method, but I guess I can't do that in illustrator.

Comment: @Evan, You could... as noted int he answer. Set the Shading to "no shading", Position it as you need, then use `Object > Expand Appearance` to create standard shapes which can be filled with color, gradients, or patterns. In addition, you can use **Symbols** to map a pattern to one side of the shape. It *can* be done.

Comment: I think that wouldn't work with a curved path though (which I also need), would it? This method seems to be limited to straight paths.

Comment: @Evan curves work as well. `:)` you're awfully defeatist here `:)` 
 A lot can be accomplished, it's merely a matter of *how* and without knowing the entire scope of what's needed, well.... I'm merely providing information based upon the bits you're dishing out. Answer updated.

Comment: I appreciate all your effort! This should come in handy! I should have been more clear though. For the current task, I need a curved *path* rather than a curved *floor*.

Comment: Well, I don't know what that means. It's *all* a "path".

Comment: There is an explanation for my attitude: 1 - I've already submitted the project in which I used the hack, and I'm just curious for future projects, and 2 - I have Solidworks...

Comment: @Evan illustrator is not 3D i any way. each effect is a one way street. I mean its not hard to make a path extruide as a effect. But as theres no 3d data each thing needs to be programmed separately so there would be no general synergy. 2 solidowks is capable of making vector shapes then just fill in illustrator. 3 theres always a trade of. Because sold works is a indirect modeler some thinsg get hard to do. But since illustrator is a direct 2d modeller you need to do a lot more work.

Comment: Evan - I agree with @joojaa here - not the right tool in many ways - but you can use the same profile you created to extrude with some variation and do a partial revolve of it, and assembly that visually with the extruded graphic to get a path with a linear component and a single-radius curve component.
Multiple curves, long poly-line paths etc are way outside Illustrator's scope as a basic 2D vector art tool.
There *is* a plugin which allows for integrated use of Maxon's Cinema4D, and that *might* help with this kind of thing.